Is it too late to just paint exterior of house this year in Missouri when unknown siding type has old cracking paint on it?
I do not know the type of siding, fibrous... It is one foot tall panels, covered in cracking latex.
At least one panel, low to ground area seems to be latex over oil painted.
I do not know if to sand, wood putty, whole house or just HOW to fix it.
I am scared to sand such thin paint off of this compressed material, may destroy the siding.
I want to get the house sealed before winter.


This looks like hardboard siding to me (a.k.a. "Masonite"). You don't repair such siding. You can attempt to reseal it, but if the surface is degraded to the point of failure it's time for replacement. The basic steps are scrape, caulk (around trim, etc.), prime, paint.
As to whether you can do it yet this year, that's a matter of the products you choose and the weather that happens. Read labels. Watch the forecast. Make a decision. We can't do that for you.
